# QueryStringParameter for SqlDataSource for Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a `SqlDataSource` and want to filter it based on query string. However using `SelectParameters` / `QueryStringParameter`, it doesn't seem to pass the value to the stored procedure.

The data source is configured like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sqlGetDetails"
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlDbConnectionString.ConnectionString %>'
     SelectCommand= "GetDetails" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     <asp:SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="AppID" QueryStringField="AppID" DbType="String" Direction="Input" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/>
     </asp:SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It fails with error:

> Procedure or function 'GetDetails' expects parameter '@AppID', which was not supplied

The stored procedure was created with code like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDetails]
    @AppID NCHAR(40)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Details 
    WHERE dbo.Details.AppID = @AppID
END
GO
```

Stack trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'GetDetails' expects >parameter '@AppID', which was not supplied.]    >System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2444190    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5775712    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4169    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) +409    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2127    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +911    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +64    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +240    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41    System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +139    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +136    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +86    System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1474    System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +22    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74    System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114  System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   +75    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +92    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +883

Comment: Are you putting appid parameter in the URL?

Comment: Change Direction="Input" to Direction="Output"    OR try to keep it  simple  <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="AppID" QueryStringField="AppID" />

Comment: <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="AppID" QueryStringField="AppID" /> was the first thing I tried. I tried changing to output it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Your SelectCommand must look like:

```
From:

SelectCommand= "GetDetails"

To:

SelectCommand= "GetDetails 12"
```

`12` serve as a parameter.

I never tried if you can pass something like

```
SelectCommand= "GetDetails AppID//Serve as the value".. Just think about it.
```